Box Shadow and Overflow in HTML/CSS
I created an container in Html which holds multiple divs, but only 3 divs are visible and other divs are hidden in overflow which u can see by scrolling x axis (Overflow: auto).
I have given box-shadow to each child div, but the thing is the half of the shadow hides in parent div because Y axis overflow is hidden.
This is my code for HTML and CSS.

This is the output of this code. As you can see the shadow of bottom of each div hides in parent container.
I want shadow like this.

You can see the shadow at bottom is full and not hidden. But for that I need to remove every overflow which cause other divs visible.
Is there anything I can do to solve this? Increasing the bottom and top margin is also not fixing the issue.
Please Help!


body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container div {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 2em);
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1em 2em;
  background-color: red;
  --tw-shadow: 0 25px 50px -12px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 25px 50px -12px var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>




Add padding-bottom: 1em; to the .container, and adjust the padding value depending on the shadow value.

I added .container { padding-bottom: 40px;} and it looks like shadow is completey visible. Try it out.

To give some space you can give the container some padding at the bottom - you need to move the scroll bar away from the shadow rather than try to have the shadow over it.


body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.container div {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 2em);
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1em 2em;
  background-color: red;
  --tw-shadow: 0 25px 50px -12px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 25px 50px -12px var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>



